# Help understanding the TI TPS22917 load switch

Tags: integrated-circuit, switching, texas-instruments

I'm playing around with a TPS22917 load switch on its own (not in a larger circuit), and there are two things that don't make sense to me:

1. When the ON pin is set to low, I see ~0.9 - 1.0v on VOUT. Shouldn't VOUT be 0v when the load switch is disabled (low)? Here is how I have it wired (my test circuit doesn't currently have the 1uF cap on VIN that the datasheet specifies):

[image: Disabled load switch]

2. I removed 5v from VIN and hooked up my multimeter to VIN + GND. Then I connected 5v to VOUT to see if I would be able to measure any backflow voltage. This fried the chip (smoke and all). Why does this happen? The behavior that I would want would be for this to work like a manual switch where nothing conducts when the switch is off. Am I doing something wrong here? Is a different type of part more appropriate for this sort of application?

[image: Voltage on VOUT]

I have read through the TPS22917 data sheet multiple times now and I'm clearly missing something. I'm a newbie so please forgive my ignorance. I specifically bought this part to test the scenario where someone puts voltage on VOUT. Trying to learn more about how to protect my circuits. I thought this part would successfully ignore anything on VOUT when the load switch isn't powered. Guess I was wrong! Any insights would be really helpful for my learning.

Comment: The datasheet contains a table under "8.5 Functional modes", that shows that the output is floating in the off mode for your configuration. That could explain you measuring some off state (ghost) voltage on the output.

Comment: @Unimportant ah thank you! I will try shorting VOUT to QOD. The data sheet says you can do this if you don’t want to configure a specific resistor value to control the output discharge.